# Converting Web App to Mobile App using NativeScript

Tags: cordova, nativescript

I have read this nice blog post
https://auth0.com/blog/converting-your-web-app-to-mobile/

I would like to ask:

Could NativeScript do the same conversion as Cordova?

Regards
Mahmoud

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript takes a different approach then Cordova.

Cordova (and frameworks using Cordova, like Ionic) basically takes your web application and runs it in a small browser-like component called WebView. Your UI is not native, it is just HTML styled with css to look like native components.

NativeScript is similar in a way you are writing a web application, but you are not using HTML elements, you are using NativeScript elements that are mapped to real native elements. When you actually build the application, you have real native application, which should give you more performance. Your code runs in a JS virtual machine, which is bundled with the app.

In short, yes it can do something similar to Cordova - reuse your web application code for mobile apps, but the build process and resulting app is different.

Comment: The part about Cordova is mostly about Ionic.